# Combine two tables

Tags: sql

Supose these 3 tables:

**SHIP :**

```
    ID                   
--------------------

    1                           
    2                            
    3
```

**ARRIVE:**

```
 shipID     Atime 
--------------------
     1       t1 
     1       t3
```

**LEAVE:**

```
 shipID     Ltime
--------------------
     1       t2
     1       t4
```

I need a query that returns :

```
  shipID   Atime   Ltime
------------------------------
    1       t1       null
    1      null       t2
    1       t3       null
    1      null       t4
```

where t1>t2>t3>t4

this result is acceptable to :

```
  shipID   Atime   Ltime
------------------------------
    1       t1       null
    1       t3       null
    1      null       t2
    1      null       t4
```

Comment: Row 2 in the original table starts with a ship ID of 2, but then arrive and leave (in the same row corresponding to ship ID 2) show ship IDs of 1. Is that correct?

Comment: Why on separate rows? Why not have t1 and t2 in same row? Same for t3 and t4.

Comment: it's all about shipID = 1, 2 and 3 don't matter here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT shipID, atime, null ltime from arrive
UNION ALL 
SELECT shipID, null atime, ltime from `leave`
order by coalesce(atime,ltime)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bb5/6).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.shipid,
  a.atime,
  l.ltime
FROM
(
    SELECT shipID, atime AS time from arrive
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT shipID, ltime AS time from `leave`
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN arrive  AS a ON a.shipid = t1.shipid AND a.atime = t1.time
LEFT JOIN `leave` AS l ON l.shipid = t1.shipid AND l.ltime = t1.time
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bb5/4)

This will give you:

```
| SHIPID |  ATIME |  LTIME |
----------------------------
|      1 |     t1 | (null) |
|      1 |     t3 | (null) |
|      1 | (null) |     t2 |
|      1 | (null) |     t4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you want to order by interleaved values as opposed to ordering by one whole column, then the other...

```
--Dummy Tables
CREATE TABLE #ship (ID int)
CREATE TABLE #arrive (ID int, atime DateTime)
CREATE TABLE #leave (ID int, ltime DateTime)

--Dummy Data
INSERT INTO #ship (ID) values (1);
INSERT INTO #arrive (ID, atime) VALUES (1, '2013-05-29 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #arrive (ID, atime) VALUES (1, '2013-05-29 12:00:00')
INSERT INTO #leave (ID, ltime) VALUES (1, '2013-05-29 06:00:00')
INSERT INTO #leave (ID, ltime) VALUES (1, '2013-05-29 18:00:00')


SELECT 
    i.ID,
    CASE WHEN i.label = 'l' then i.thetime else null end as atime,
    CASE WHEN i.label = 'a' then i.thetime else null end as ltime
FROM (
         SELECT 'l' as label,ID,atime as thetime FROM #arrive 
         UNION
         SELECT 'a' as label,ID,ltime as thetime FROM #leave 
     ) as i
ORDER BY i.thetime

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #ship
DROP TABLE #arrive
DROP TABLE #leave
```

Results in.

```
ID          atime                   ltime
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2013-05-29 00:00:00.000 NULL
1           NULL                    2013-05-29 06:00:00.000
1           2013-05-29 12:00:00.000 NULL
1           NULL                    2013-05-29 18:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **`Query`**

```
select * from
(select s.id as shipid,a.Atime as Atime,null as Ltime
from Ship s
inner join Arrival a on s.id=a.shipid
union
select s.id as shipid,null as Atime, l.Ltime as Ltime
from Ship s
left join Leave1 l on s.id=l.shipid)t
where t.Atime is not null
or t.Ltime is not null
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d987/6)**